# How to read rfid tag no from HID iClass reader in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, hid

I have a HID iClass outdoor reader. I want to read the RFID tag no using this reader. I already written code in serialport using c# but after run its always return ???? (questions marks).

I used rs232 to usb converter (prolific).

Please help me any one have idea about this.

Please find output screenshot

[image]

Comment: Its more likely the console is unable to display the bytes received as characters.  Debug and look at the content of the data you receive at the byte level.

Comment: Check BaudRate,Parity, DataBits, StopBits, Handshake so that are the same as is set up on device

Comment: @S.Petrosov I crosscheck with device all the parameters are correct. Its always return these ???? (question marks).

Comment: @AlexK. I am using ReadExisting function in DataReceived event.

Comment: Can you post the code in your DataReceived event function?

Comment: @Neil.  string data = _serialPort.ReadExisting(); Console.WriteLine(data); _serialPort is the instance of SerialPort class.

Comment: It is not returning `?` it is unable to decode the data received to a valid string, or the console is not using the correct encoding.  In the somewhat unlikely event that you expect UTF8 text to be returned set Console.Encoding to UTF8 then ensure the SerialPort has the correct .Encoding as this controls what .ReadExisting uses.   The best way to do what your trying is to read the data into a buffer (port.Read()) then look at the bytes, from there you can do whatever you like.

Comment: @AlexK. I written data read function and its returning as same question marks.  int bytes = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
                _serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer); Console.WriteLine(result);

Comment: ... Yes, `Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 200, 201, 202 }));` would also print **`???`** because the bytes 200,201,202 are not valid characters.  You need to look at the raw data in `buffer`, whatever it is it is probably not meant to be interpreted as text.

Comment: @AlexK. Is the HID reader encrypted the data?. Is there any decryption algorithm required for this or same serial port code will work.

Comment: its not encrypted its simply not text (or text with a different encoding)   Look at the documentation to see what it is supposed to return.

Comment: @AlexK. It suppose to return rfid tag no (04000). Can you please help me on this.

Comment: If you are reading tags is data xml or html?  with both you need to receive all the data before searching for tags.  So I suspect you don't have a compete document.  I usually start checking issues like this by confirming the bytes count in the receive code matches the byte count of the data sent.  If they do not match then find out why the sizes do not match.

Comment: @jdweng I am taking about RFID tag no HTML or XML tag.

Comment: Still any communications algorithm over serial ports you need complete data before sending to a reader.  Make sure you are sending the reader the correct number of bytes.

Comment: @ParthaRanjan I agree with AlexK, the encoding is wrong. Try 'Encoding.Default.GetString(...) instead.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable support. I cross check with HID vendor with device configuration. I convert the data to hexa and then hexa to binary and finally get the result. The baud rate and data parity is slightly different.